# RabbitMQ delete queue can not release connection

Tags: java, queue, rabbitmq, message-queue, amqp

on my java program, some kind of messages  are being sent over RabbitMQ queues as below :

```
 if(!con.isConnected()){
        log.error("Not connected !!!");

        return false;
}
con.getChannel().basicPublish("",queueName, MessageProperties.PERSISTENT_BASIC, bytes)
```

1. I deleted queues via RabbitMQ management GUI plugin
2. try to send a message over that deleted queue

**Result:** queues were deleted from RabbitMQ GUI but when I am trying to send message over that deleted RabbitMQ queues, connection is still alive.(con.isConnected() == true ) I need to find a way to listen the queue, if it is deleted , I shouldn't send any message to the deleted queue.

Note: After deleting queue, I am not restarting RabbitMQ.

channel creation :

```
 channel = connection.createChannel();
 channel.queueDeclare(prop.getQueueName(), true, false, false, null);
```

example code channel, queue,exchange creation :

```
ConnectionFactory cf = new ConnectionFactory();
    cf.setUsername("guest");
    cf.setPassword("guest");
    cf.setHost("localhost");
    cf.setPort(5672);
    cf.setAutomaticRecoveryEnabled(true);
    cf.setConnectionTimeout(10000);
    cf.setNetworkRecoveryInterval(10000);
    cf.setTopologyRecoveryEnabled(true);
    cf.setRequestedHeartbeat(5);
    Connection connection = cf.newConnection();

    channel = connection.createChannel();
    channel.queueDeclare("test", true, false, false, null);
    channel.exchangeDeclare("testExchange", "direct",true);
    channel.queueBind("test", "testExchange", "testRoutingKey");

    connection.addShutdownListener(new ShutdownListener() {

        @Override
        public void shutdownCompleted(ShutdownSignalException cause) {
            System.out.println("test"+cause);
        }
    });
```

Sending message :

```
            channel.basicPublish("testExchange", "testRoutingKey", null,messageBodyBytes);
```

Comment: Please share some code so we can - at least - try to help you.

Comment: I am not sure  that code block helps you to understand the situation but anyway I added it .

Comment: Please share the code where you are connecting to the queue...

Comment: please share what you pass to `basicPublish`. IIRC you cannot publish to a queue directly, but only to an exchange. The default exchanges allow you to pass a queue name I guess, if that queue exists. Also a connection has nothing to do with a queue, so if you delete the queue, connections are still valid.

Comment: As I understood, there is a way to send messages directly to the related queue , please check the RabbitMQ Durability part : [link](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-java.html)

Comment: I just need a queue listener which sends notifications about queue's status such as deleted,created,recreated ... Or may be if I declare some exchanges and bind them with related queues then when I try to send message to deleted queue by using the exchange , Rabbitmq will throw an exception about the queue is not exist anymore.

Comment: declared the testqueue, bound it with testExchange with testRoutingKey and I can successfully send a message to the queue. But I removed the queue via RabbitMQ GUI and then tried to send another message via java application, message was sent but I expected to receive an exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From RabbitMQ google

> Messages in AMQP 0-9-1 are not published to queues; they are published to exchanges, from where they
>   are routed to a queue (or another exchange) or not. [1]
>   basic.publish is a completely asynchronous protocol method by design: there is no response for it
>   unless you ask for it [2]. Messages that are unroutable can be returned to the publisher
>   if you define a return listener and publish with the mandatory flag set to true.
>   Note that publisher confirms and the mandatory flag/returns are orthogonal and one does not imply
>   the other.

Defining return listener and setting mandatory flag true was solved my problem. If any message was not routed , I can catch them by using ReturnListener and add to my persisted queue to send another time when system becomes active.